# URL Not changing, document source code 'hidden'

Tags: html, url

I'm looking at this website: http://fitzfitzpatrick.com/
The source code is bare minimal and can see that this is done via frames.
When I click a link on the page the URL doesnt change and the frame src also doesn't change so how is the content different?

Any pointers to reading material, or a basic explanation of how this voodoo trickery is occurring would be splendid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No voodoo trickery; that's how frames work. That page is just basically pulling in another website into that frame, so any request is actually happening within the frame itself. Same thing happens in an iframe, you can click around in the iframe to your hearts content and nothing in the URL will change because it's happening within the frame.

In this particular instance, http://www.cargocollective.com/fitzfitzpatrick is being pulled into a frame that spans the entire window on http://fitzfitzpatrick.com/, so it's basically like an independent window housed in it's own window if that makes sense.